# Collapsing toolbar decreasing the views size when its collaps

Tags: android-studio, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

[image][image]

In collapsing toolbar i want to decrease the size of the views(image view, text views and button) at the time of toolbar start collapsing.
  By default its decreases only toolbar-title size but i want decreas whole layout which inside the collapsing toolbar.
Thank you in advance.